# Mongo find documents that do not contain a given value (using $not)

Tags: mongodb

I have two items in MongoDB:

```
{'title':'active item',
 'tags':[
        {'tag':'active'},
        {'tag':'anothertag'}
]}
{'title':'completed item',
 'tags':[
        {'tag':'completed'}
]}
```

It works to find items which are tagged as completed:

```
db.items.find({'tags.tag':'completed'})
RESULT: [<completed item>]
```

Now, I want to select all items which are not tagged as completed, so I tried:

```
db.items.find({$not:{'tags.tag':'completed'}})
DESIRED RESULT: [<active item>]
ACTUAL RESULT: []
```

But somehow this doesn't return any results.  Clearly I misunderstand $not in Mongo, but why?  How do I query to find the records that do not contain a given value in their tags?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The target of the [`$not`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/#op._S_not) operator needs to be an operator-expression, not a field/value object.

So parvin's answer is the easiest way to do this, but just for learning purposes, you can do this with `$not` by using `$not` supported expressions like:

```javascript
db.items.find({tags: {$not: {$elemMatch: {tag: 'completed'}}}})

db.items.find({'tags.tag': {$not: /completed/}})
```

Comment: When I first read the docs for $elemMatch, I didn't understand it.  But your answer provides a clear use of $elemMatch.  Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

You can do it with [$ne](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) operator.

```
db.items.find({"tags.tag" : {$ne : "completed"}})
```

Comment: +1 It works, but why?  With my SQL background, I thought $ne would improperly exclude items that don't have any tags.  Why doesn't $not do what I want?