# mongodb using $not getting undefined, in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make a find command in Mongo using `$not` as i see in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803512/mongo-find-documents-that-do-not-contain-a-given-value-using-not),

```
await Match.find(
        {
          type:"Friendly", status:"Pending", "date.fullDate":{$gt: date},
          $not:{$or: [{"team1.players":{$elemMatch: {_id:playerId}}}, {"team2.players":{$elemMatch: {_id:playerId}}}]}
        }).sort({'date.fullDate':1}).exec(function(err, doc) {
          console.log(doc)
        return res.send({data: doc});
        });
```

However, i am getting `undefined`.
I am thinking the problem is with the `$not` because when i remove it and make the command like this it works.

```
await Match.find(
        {
          type:"Friendly", status:"Pending", "date.fullDate":{$gt: date},
          $or: [{"team1.players":{$elemMatch: {_id:playerId}}}, {"team2.players":{$elemMatch: {_id:playerId}}}]
        }).sort({'date.fullDate':1}).exec(function(err, doc) {
          console.log(doc)
        return res.send({data: doc});
        });
```

Note: that team2 could be null in the documents.
Any ideas why i am getting this `undefined`.
My document look like this:

```
match:{
  team1:{
    players:[
              _id:value,
              otherfields...
    ]
  },
  team2:{
    players:[
              _id:value,
              otherfields...
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use `$nor` instead of `$not:{$or:[]}`

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092984/mongodb-using-not-and-and-together).

Answer (score 1):

```
await Match.find({
    type: "Friendly", status: "Pending", "date.fullDate": { $gt: date },
    $or: [
        {
            $not: {
                "team1.players": { $elemMatch: { _id: playerId } }
            }
        },
        {
            $not: {
                "team2.players": { $elemMatch: { _id: playerId } }
            }
        }
    ]
}).sort({ 'date.fullDate': 1 }).exec(function (err, doc) {
    console.log(doc)
    return res.send({ data: doc });
});
```